# Is zlib for real?

Tags: compression

Not really a programming question but rather an "i can't believe my eyeballs" question.

Basically, I wanted to see what kind of space savings I could give my search engine project if I could compress some of the fields. Enter zlib, using the "compress" function it dropped the size of the sample data from ~7mb to ~7kb and im like "gtf out of here". The sample data is a list of almost 2 million integer ID's, in ascending order up to the value of ~8 million.

To double check, I compressed the data again, saved in a file, opened the compressed data in another program, uncompressed and checked for errors, nothing, its flawless. I still can't wrap my head around it though, I mean sure, my test data can be characterized as rather predictable but 99.9% compression ratio?

Am I hallucinating again or did I miss something or what?

Comment: You should see what zlib does with black bitmaps.  99.99999% compression ratio.

Comment: @MikeNakis: zlib's maximum compression ratio is 1032:1.

Comment: @MarkAdler Really? There goes another idol of mine, destroyed.

Comment: If you get that compression ratio, you can probably compress it with zlib again to make it smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that does sound a little odd.  zlib will in fact compress a string of the same byte repeated forever by about 1000:1, but most other data would not compress that well.  You may want to check your data to see if it is really what you think it is.

Comment: right you are! It took me forever to figure it out but I made the noob mistake of saving/loading the data as strings (as opposed to binary). Due to this the original data got cut off by a null terminator or something and as a result there was a lot less data to compress and the process was invisible to my error checking too. 

The actual compressed size turned out to be ~800kb which is similar to what winrar does to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Your character space consists of digits from 0 to 9, mostly towards the bottom and probably with a lot of repeating digits for large chunks of your file besides the last few digits.

Why would you be surprised it's relatively easy to compress so much going from 256 possible characters down to just 10?

Comment: Note that that _by itself_, going from 256 symbols to 10 symbols, would only give you a compression ratio of 0.415.  Not 0.001.